# Is it possible to display list of users as a web part?

Tags: 2010, list

I have someone who wants all members of their SP group to be displayed in the home page of their sub site, as a list. Is it possible to grab users from the users and groups page, turn it into a list or web part, and embed elsewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Site Users Web Part and select the group to display:
[image]